# Ansible shell module returns error when grep results are empty

Tags: grep, ansible

I am using Ansible's shell module to find a particular string and store it in a variable. But if grep did not find anything I am getting an error.

Example:

```
- name: Get the http_status
  shell: grep "http_status=" /var/httpd.txt
  register: cmdln
  check_mode: no
```

When I run this Ansible playbook if `http_status` string is not there, playbook is stopped. I am not getting stderr.

How can I make Ansible run without interruption even if the string is not found?

Comment: my question if empty also i want to run the ansible without interption

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Like you observed, ansible will stop execution if the `grep` exit code is not zero. You can ignore it with `ignore_errors`.

Another trick is to pipe the grep output to `cat`. So `cat` exit code will always be zero since its stdin is grep's stdout. It works if there is a match and also when there is no match. Try it.

```
- name: Get the http_status
  shell: grep "http_status=" /var/httpd.txt | cat
  register: cmdln
  check_mode: no
```

Answer (score 71):

`grep` by design returns code 1 if the given string was not found. Ansible by design stops execution if the return code is different from 0. Your system is working properly.

To prevent Ansible from stopping playbook execution on this error, you can:

- add `ignore_errors: yes` parameter to the task
- use `failed_when:` parameter with a proper condition

Because `grep` returns error code 2 for exceptions, the second method seems more appropriate, so:

```
- name: Get the http_status
  shell: grep "http_status=" /var/httpd.txt
  register: cmdln
  failed_when: "cmdln.rc == 2"
  check_mode: no
```

You might also consider adding `changed_when: false` so that the task won't be reported as "changed" every single time.

All options are described in the [Error Handling In Playbooks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_error_handling.html) document.

Comment: bonus points for including some real fail condition detection via failed_when, and the suggestion of using changed_when: false to avoid the appearance of system changes in the Ansible output!