# Ansible task fails, even with ignore_errors

Tags: ansible, homebrew, homebrew-cask

So I'm new to Ansible, but I've been researching, and I can't find any articles that would explain this issue. I've created a role to install brew cask applications, but it keeps 'failing' while running a command to check if the application is already installed.

Here's the task:

```
- name: "Check for installed casks (Applications)"
  shell: brew cask list | grep {{ item }}
  register: installed_applications
  with_items: "{{ apps }}"
  when: apps is defined
  ignore_errors: yes
```

So, from what I understand, it will run the command with an item from my list of applications, so the example command would be `brew cask list | grep keybase`, and then map that to `installed_applications`.

But when I run it, I end up seeing all of the applications failing (there not installed). Here's the error in verbose mode:

```
failed: [localhost] (item=keybase) => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "brew cask list | grep keybase",
    "delta": "0:00:00.792680",
    "end": "2017-03-03 19:41:05.500378",
    "failed": true,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "brew cask list | grep keybase",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "warn": false
        },
        "module_name": "command"
    },
    "item": "keybase",
    "rc": 1,
    "start": "2017-03-03 19:41:04.707698",
    "stderr": "",
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": [],
    "warnings": []
}
```

If I run the command manually I just get a blank output (as it should), but Ansible should be ignoring errors, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `shell` tasks are marked as failed, because `grep` return non-zero exit code when no match found.
So you get `rc: 1` and `failed: true`.

But saying `ignore_errors: yes` you tell Ansible: *keep going even if task failed*.
So the task is red and marked as failed, but subsequent tasks get executed.

If you want the task to be green even if grep failed, use `bash` tricks or use `failed_when` condition. You can search for `[ansible] grep` on SO. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41011953/2795592).