# ansible playbook fails when grep is not finding anything

Tags: regex, grep, ansible

Trying to run simple ansible playbook command:

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Check errors during package installation
      shell: sudo dpkg -l | grep -c '^i[^i]'
      register: result
      notify: Fix problems with packages
  handlers:
    - name: Fix problems with packages
      shell: sudo dpkg --configure --pending
      when: result.stdout != "0"
```

But getting an error:

```
failed: [jasper01.stage2.qa.whs] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "sudo dpkg -l | grep -c '^i[^i]'", "delta": "0:00:00.045734", "end": "2017-05-15 13:18:14.157175", "rc": 1, "start": "2017-05-15 13:18:14.111441", "warnings": []}
stdout: 0

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

If i'm changing my regex to ***'^i[i]'*** - it's running fine, but it's not what i need.
What could be the reason, and how to bypass this?

Comment: I think, you want to extract package count starting with i, am I right..? Then you could change your command to sudo dpkg -l | awk '{ print $2}' | grep -c '^i'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ansible shell module returns error when grep results are empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010378/ansible-shell-module-returns-error-when-grep-results-are-empty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your grep is not finding anything, so it 
returns rc=1 which ansible interprets as the task failing, you can use 
`ignore_errors: yes` or `failed_when: false` to bypass this 'failure', and do not use `sudo`, use `become`.

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
    - name: Check errors during package installation
      shell: dpkg -l | grep -c '^i[^i]'
      ignore_errors: yes
      register: result
      notify: Fix problems with packages
  handlers:
    - name: Fix problems with packages
      shell: dpkg --configure --pending
      when: result.stdout != "0"
```

Comment: `ignore_errors: yes` - didn't work, but `failed_when: false` helped.
Thank you.

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score =(