# Checking if process is running

Tags: ansible

I have written a small playbook that checks to see if a given process is running on the host machine. I have written this as follows:

```
- name: checking process running for clients and start process when not
  service:
    name: marketaccess {{ item.key|lower }} -vi
    state: started
  register: process
  with_dict: "{{ customers }}"
```

When the dictionary's item.key = BROADWAY and the process I am trying to check is as follows :

[image]

But when I run this playbook the error that is reported is:

> Could not find the requested service marketacces broadway -vi: host

Please can someone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 4):

I have used pgrep since "ps -ef" output varies between the servers (at least in my case).

```
- name: "Get process PID"
  shell: >
    echo -n
    $(pgrep {{ item.binary_name }})
  args:
    executable: "{{ shell_path }}"
  register: my_procs
```

Answer (score 1):

> Please can someone see what I am doing wrong?

[Service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd#Core_components_and_libraries) is not the same as [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)) in computing.

There is no module to manage/check processes in Ansible. You can use the command included in the question with `shell` module (pay attention to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41010653/2947502)), register the result and run a task to start the process.

However, it is equally possible that your `marketaccess` is in fact a service, or that yet another service creates child processes. There is no way to tell. Refer to the manual of your software.

You can provide arguments to the [`service` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/service_module.html) as `arguments` parameter.

Comment: Hi techraf, Do you know if a module exists to check processes that are running rather than services?

Answer (score 0):

As per the ansible documentation its better to use the "pid" module to check if there are any processes running. References are below
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/pids_module.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There's a new windows module on ansible that can be used for this purpose.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_wait_for_process_module.html#examples

You can find the process name:

1. Right-click on the process in task manager
2. Open properties
3. Copy the name WITHOUT extension