# Ansible error on shell command returning zero

Tags: ansible

Ansible doesn't seem to be able to handle the result '0' for shell commands. This

```
- name: Check if swap exists
  shell: "swapon -s | grep -ci dev"
  register: swap_exists
```

Returns an error

> "msg": "non-zero return code"

But when I replace "dev" with "type", which actually always occurs and gives a count of at least 1, then the command is successful and no error is thrown.

I also tried with `command:` instead of `shell:` - it doesn't give an error, but then the command is also not executed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

since you want to run a sequence of commands that involve pipe, ansible states you should use `shell` and not `command`, as you are doing.

So, the problem is the fact that grep returns 1 (didnt find a match on the swapon output), and ansible considers this a failure. Since you are well sure there is no issue, just add a `ignore_errors: true` and be done with it.

```
- name: Check if swap exists
  shell: "swapon -s | grep -ci non_existent_string"
  register: swap_exists
  ignore_errors: true
```

**OR:**

if you want to narrow it down to return codes 0 and 1, instruct ansible to not consider failures those 2 rcs:

```
- name: Check if swap exists
  shell: "swapon -s | grep -ci non_existent_string"
  register: swap_exists
  # ignore_errors: true
  failed_when: swap_exists.rc != 1 and swap_exists.rc != 0
```

Comment: Your answer is good in a strict way, and a good learning example. But for what I'm trying to do, realizing that there is the 'ansible fact' ansible_swaptotal_mb that immediately indicates whether there is a swap in the system or not, actually points to a better solution :)

Comment: i agree, i would prefer the ansible facts too if they can provide me the information i need :)

Comment: I believe that `failed_when:` is much better than `ignore_errors: true`! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a better way. if you only need to know the record number this works:

```html
- name: Check if swap exists
  shell: "swapon -s | grep -i dev|wc -l"
  register: swap_exists
```

Another way is to always use cat at the end of the pipe. See [Ansible shell module returns error when grep results are empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010378/ansible-shell-module-returns-error-when-grep-results-are-empty/41010653)

```html
    - name: Check if swap exists
      shell: "swapon -s | grep -i dev|cat"
      register: swap_exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also parse the `grep` count result in `awk` and return your custom output. This will avoid the ignore_errors module.

```
- name: Check if swap exists
  shell: "swapon -s | grep -ci dev" | awk '{ r = $0 == 0 ? "false":"true"; print r }'
  register: swap_exists
```