# How to check for a process if running then exit else remove and install a package

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, ansible-inventory

I need to check for a process on few remote hosts, if the process is running then exit without doing anything, if the process is not running then remove the existing package and install a different version.

I have tried the below ansible code, but I am not sure in ansible how to exit if the process is already running. Can someone please help here? Thanks in advance.

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  tasks:
    - name: check if http is running
      shell: "pgrep http"
      register: running_processes
      failed_when: running_processes.rc > 1

    - debug:
        var: running_processes

    - block:
       - debug:
           msg: http is running. End of play.
       - meta: end_host
      when: running_processes.stdout_lines|length > 0

    - debug:
        msg: http is not running. Continue play.

    - name: remove the old http package
      yum:
        name: http
        state: absent

    - name: install http
      yum:
        name: http.rpm
        state: present
```

But I am getting below error while running this playbook.

```
fatal: [host1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'running_processes.stdout_lines|length > 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (running_processes.stdout_lines|length > 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'http.yml': line 14, column 10, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    - block:\n       - debug:\n         ^ here\n"}
```

Output of running_processes

```
ok: [host1] => {
    "running_processes": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "pgrep http",
        "delta": "0:00:00.025309",
        "end": "2019-08-26 14:44:21.019275",
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "msg": "non-zero return code",
        "rc": 1,
        "start": "2019-08-26 14:44:20.993966",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}
```

I am not getting this error now, but - meta: end_host is throwing an error.

```
ERROR! invalid meta action requested: end_host

The error appears to have been in 'http.yml': line 20, column 10, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

         msg: http is running. End of play.
       - meta: end_host
         ^ here
```

It is working as expected where the process is running. But it is skipping where the process is not running.

```
ok: [host1] => {
    "running_processes": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "pgrep http",
        "delta": "0:00:00.019929",
        "end": "2019-08-26 16:57:59.940856",
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "rc": 0,
        "start": "2019-08-26 16:57:59.920927",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "8743",
        "stdout_lines": [
            "8743"
        ]
    }
}
ok: [host2] => {
    "running_processes": {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "pgrep http",
        "delta": "0:00:00.018915",
        "end": "2019-08-26 16:57:59.338179",
        "failed": false,
        "failed_when_result": false,
        "msg": "non-zero return code",
        "rc": 1,
        "start": "2019-08-26 16:57:59.319264",
        "stderr": "",
        "stderr_lines": [],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": []
    }
}

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "msg": "http is running. End of play."
}
skipping: [host2]
ERROR! invalid meta action requested: end_host

The error appears to have been in 'http.yml': line 19, column 10, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

           msg: http is running. End of play.
       - meta: end_host
         ^ here
```

Comment: Error: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'  can't be valid.

Comment: `end_host` is valid choice of [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html#meta-execute-ansible-actions). Indentation of `msg` in both `debug` tasks is wrong.

Comment: I tried to fix the indentation of msg on both the debug, still I am getting the end_host error. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: `end_host` has been added to [meta](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/meta_module.html#meta-execute-ansible-actions) in Ansible 2.8. Either upgrade or use [fail](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html#fail-fail-with-custom-message)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(ansible 2.8.3)</sup>

Use *`pgrep`* to avoid [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41010378/ansible-shell-module-returns-error-when-grep-results-are-empty/), e.g.

```yaml
    - name: check if httpd is running
      shell: "pgrep httpd"
      register: running_processes
      failed_when: running_processes.rc > 1

    - block:
        - debug:
            msg: httpd is running. End of play.
        - meta: end_play
      when: running_processes.stdout_lines|length > 0

    - debug:
        msg: httpd is not running. Continue play.
```

---

Notes

1. Equivalent condition is

```yaml
      when: running_processes.rc == 0
```

2. *`- meta: end_play`* terminates all hosts. Use *`- meta: end_host`* to end current host only.

---

Below is the example of *`running_processes`* when there is no match

```yaml
    ok: [localhost] => {
        "running_processes": {
            "changed": true, 
            "cmd": "pgrep httpd", 
            "delta": "0:00:00.013312", 
            "end": "2019-08-26 20:40:59.908060", 
            "failed": false, 
            "failed_when_result": false, 
            "msg": "non-zero return code", 
            "rc": 1, 
            "start": "2019-08-26 20:40:59.894748", 
            "stderr": "", 
            "stderr_lines": [], 
            "stdout": "", 
            "stdout_lines": []
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have updated the question with the current playbook

Comment: I am not sure how to get this output

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir, I got the running_processes output now, but looks like - meta: end_host is throwing an error